# Why am I getting this error when using Twitter Rest API

Tags: python, api, twitter, oauth, machine-learning

This is my first post here so I'm sorry if my question is weird/dumb.

I'm using this book -> Building Machine Learning Systems with Python to learn.

In chapter 6 we have to download this corpora of tweets by Niek Sanders ( ~ 5000ish tweets), I found the code online on the authors github --> [here](https://github.com/luispedro/BuildingMachineLearningSystemsWithPython/tree/master/ch06) and used my twitter app account and entered all the keys and tokens in the twitter auth.py file. However when I run the install.py file, it downloads 5 tweets and spits out the following error at me:

```
We will skip 1107 tweets that are not available or visible any more on twitter
We have already downloaded 5 tweets.
Fetching 4779 tweets...
['apple', 'positive', '126394830791254016']
--> downloading tweet #126394830791254016 (1 of 4779)
Twitter sent status 404 for URL: 1.1/statuses/show.json using parameters: (id=blank&oauth_consumer_key=blank&oauth_nonce=blank&oauth_signature_method=blank&oauth_timestamp=1424721838&oauth_token=blank&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=blank)
details: {"errors":[{"code":144,"message":"No status found with that ID."}]}
```

i replaced all the keys with the word **blank** here to keep them secret

Answer (score 2):

By the look of it, it appears you are trying to pull a tweet with an invalid ID. More than likely that tweet was deleted, thereby making the id invalid.

Comment: Actually I just checked, you are right, am adding those tweet id's to not_authorized.tsv

Answer (score 0):

You must use `$tweetObject->{"id_str"}` instead of `"id"`.